# Python3 paramiko memory error with large stdout data

Tags: python, python-3.x, memory, paramiko

I am using the paramiko library to ssh into a router and run a sh operational command, in which the output is very large (> 500MB), and it throws a memory error.  Is there a way to re write my code so it doesn't put all data into memory and throw an error.

```
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh_session.execute_command(' '.join(['show operational',request,'xml'])) #request is just a str represnting the differnet components (AAA, etc.)
process_output(''.join(stdout.readlines()),request) #stdout.readlines() is what causes the memory error
ssh_session.close()
```

Error:

```
polling IPV6_RIB
Exception: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lab/5.3.2_xml/py3/lib/python3.4/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py", line 1607, in run
    raise SSHException('Expecting packet from %r, got %d' % (self._expected_packet, ptype))
paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Expecting packet from (31,), got 94

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "xml_oper.py", line 42, in <module>
    main()
  File "xml_oper.py", line 37, in main
    process_output(''.join(stdout.readlines()),request)
MemoryError
```

Comment: Have you tried the obvious: read *one* line at a time or read a fixed number of bytes at a time?

Comment: ^^^ That.... Don't use `.readlines()` with output that large - either use `readline()` to read one line at a time, or the similar iterator interface `for line in stdout:` approach...

Comment: I changed by code to the for line in stdout way, but I am still hitting the Expecting packet exception, why is it hitting this? Thanks